# Toggle to hide cell output in the HTML version

Tags: javascript, html, jupyter-notebook

The following code displays a link that shows/hides the output of the next cell:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''<script>
function code_toggle_next() {
    $('div.cell.code_cell.rendered.selected').next().find('div.output').toggle();
    }
$( document ).ready(code_toggle_next);
</script>
<a href="javascript:code_toggle_next()"> To show/hide next the output of the next cell, click here </a>.''')
```

However it doesn't seem to work once the notebook has been exported to HTML: the output of the next cell is displayed, and clicking on the link doesn't do anything.
Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the HTML file and select Inspect element or DEV tools depending on your browser, you'll see that the cell misses the class `selected`, so the first selector returns an empty result. I tried and removing that class fixes the behaviour.

However, it returns all cells instead, so if you take `.next().find('div.output')` then it will apply to all but the very first cell. It's probably better to use the `onclick` attribute. This way, you can pass the cell you clicked on as an argument to the function ([see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)) and still toggle only the following cell. Have a look:

```py
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''<script>
function toggle_next(event) {
    $(event.target).closest('div.code_cell').next().find('div.output').toggle();
}
</script>
<a onclick="toggle_next(event)"> To show/hide next the output of the next cell, click here </a>.''')
```